# Entity type MyTable is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm getting above error when trying to access data via a linq statement.
I'm using Entity Framework 6.0 and a database first approach.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
class contextHandler
{
    private MyEntities myContext;
    public void initialize()
    {
        //initialize Context

        var conn = new EntityConnection(@"metadata=res://*/Print.csdl|res://*/Print.ssdl|res://*/Print.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="";data source=SQLServer;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=ThePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"";");

        myContext = new MyEntities(conn);

    }

    public decimal getPrice(int id)
    {
        var price = from t in myContext.MyTable
                    where t.id == id
                    select t.Price;
        decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(price);
        return d;
    }
}
```

The error occures in the linq-statement in getPrice.
The code for my Context and Entity is:

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    public MyEntities(EntityConnection conn)
        : base(conn.ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class MyTable
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MyTable()
    {
        this.MyTable = new HashSet<MyTable>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    ...

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MyTable> MyTable { get; set; }
}
```

The code for the context and entity are bot auto-generated.
I'm using this in a form where I first create a new `contextHandler`, then call the `initialize()` method and later, when I need to do some calculations with the prize, I call the `getPrize(int id)` method.
Both contextHandler and myContext are not null. Still I get above message.

Could someone nudge me in the right dirction?

Comment: C# is **case sensitive** you know? `myTable` and `MyTable` have a different meaning

Comment: It's strange to get an error about something called `myEntity` where that name, whatever it is, doesn't appear in the code. Please, make an MCVE: stackoverflow.com/help/mcve